# Relation between $|H \lor K|$ , $|H|$ and $|K|$

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a finite group , then we know that the subgroup generated by $H \cup K$ i.e. $H \lor K$  is the smallest subgroup containing both $H$ and $K$ , then how can we relate the order of $H \lor K$ , $|H|$ and $|K|$ ?

Comment: I think all you will be seing from those few requirements is the obvious set-theoretic inequalities
$$|H\cup K| \le |H\vee K| \le |F|$$
Where $F$ is the common supergroup of $H,K$ you are looking at

Comment: @AlexR: What is $F$ ?

Comment: The supergroup, you didn't give it a name so I gave it one.

Comment: I think the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$ can be arbitrarily large relative to $|H|$ and $|K|$.

Comment: $|H \lor K|$ is divisible by both $|H|$ and by $|K|$. That is all that you can say.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, there is a theorem out there somewhere for the case where $H$ and $K$ are cyclic.

Comment: In fact, for any $l,m,n \ge 2$, there are finite groups with elements $x,y$ such that $|x|=l$, $|y|=m$, $|xy|=n$.